# AWS CloudWatch Agent not uploading old files

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

During the initial migration to AWS CloudWatch logging I also want legacy log files to be synced. However, it seems that only the current active file (i.e. still being updated) will be synced. The old files even match the file name format will be ignore.

So are there any easy way to upload legacy files?

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html

Comment: Migration to AWS CloudWatch logging from where? Do you mean that there is an EC2 instance where these log files are stored and the CloudWatch agent could only send the latest one to CWL ?

Comment: Also can you share the configuration of the CloudWatch Agent you have configured?

Comment: Only the file with the latest changes will be uploaded. How many of these old files do you have?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you should be able to upload all files by merging them. Or create a new `[logstream]` section for each file.

Log files in `/var/log` are usually archived periodically, for instance by `logrotate`. If the current active file is named `abcd.log`, then after a few days files will be created automatically with names like `abcd.log.1`, `abcd.log.2`...
Depending on your exact system and configuration, they can also be compressed automatically (`abcd.log.1.gz`,`abcd.log.1.gz`, ...).

The [CloudWatch Logs documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html) defines the `file` configuration parameter as such:

> file
>
> Specifies log files that you want to push to CloudWatch Logs. File can point to a specific file or multiple files (using wildcards such as /var/log/system.log*). Only the latest file is pushed to CloudWatch Logs based on file modification time.

Note : using a glob path with a star (`*`) will therefore not be sufficient to upload historical files.

Assuming that you have already configured a glob path, you could use the `touch` command sequentially on each of the historical files to trigger their upload. Problems :

- you would need to guess when the CloudWatch agent has noticed each file before proceeding to the next
- you would need to temporarily pause the current active file
- zipped files are not supported, but you can decompress them manually

Alternatively you could decompress then *aggregate all historical files in a single merged file*. In the context of the first example, you could run `cat abcd.log.* > abcd.log.merged`. This newly created file would be detected by the CloudWatch agent (matches the glob pattern) which would consider it as the active file. Problem : the previous active file could be updated simultaneously and take the lead before CloudWatch notices your merged file. If this is a concern, you could simply create a new `[logstream]` config section dedication the historical file.

Alternatively, just decompress the historical files then create a new `[logstream]` config section for each.

Please correct any bad assumptions that I made about your system.

Comment: if it worked, please assign bounty to @Caerbannog